# Jquery: How to find text in textarea

Tags: jquery, match

I have array of keywords. How can I find if any of these keywords present in textarea? Is there any plugin or function to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var words = $('#text').val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/);
var keywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2'];

var isKeywordPresent = $.grep(keywords, function(keyword, index) {
    return $.inArray(keyword, words) > 0;
}).length > 0;
```

Comment: This solution should use return $.inArray(keyword, words) > -1; $.inArray will return 0 if the first word in words matches.

Answer (score -1):

for some ideas 
@SO [Find text string using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)