# Find and Hide element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find, hyperlink

```
<a href="#">Hide Me</a>
```

How do I find a link with text "hide" in it. I know how to find links by attributes but can't figure out how to find link by its text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a:contains(Hide)')
```

Note that `contains` is case sensitive.

```
$('a:contains(Hide)').click(function() { $(this).hide() });
```

Comment: @dittodhole: it sure does. the same goes for attribute selectors, `a[href=#]`. i'm not sure if any version is officially recommended over the other, but both work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a:contains("Hide")');
```

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)
see [jQuery docu](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text)