# Search HTML Table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and need a specific column in a specific row.

```
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="important_column"><a href="/bla/blah/link">IMPORTANT INFO</a></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="need_link_here"><a href="/I/WANT/THIS/LINK/">link</a></td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
```

So if the link text in "important_column" equals the thing I'm looking for.
Get the link text in "need link_here" column. The text between `<a></a>`
How to do in jQuery?

Comment: Part of the solution: You can search for text in links with this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

Comment: I think that words 'link text' make some confusion here. Do you mean href attribute or text inside <a></a>?

Comment: Sorry if im confusing, i meant the text inside <a></a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to check to see if an element contains specific text:

```
$("table td:contains('IMPORTANT INFO')")
    .next().next()
    .children("a");
```

**EXAMPLE** - http://jsfiddle.net/Kkywt/

Comment: +1 because this is the only answer so far that doesn't use the important_column and need_link_here classes which I doubt will be present in the real situation.

Comment: Darn, I mistook myself, important_column *is* used.

Comment: @snowlord: it is, but it doesn't have to be.  The code here would work just as well without it.  In fact, I just edited the answer and the example so that you could feel like your +1 was justified ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("table tr td.important_column a[href=/bla/blah/link]").length) {
   var link = $("table tr td.need_link_here a").attr("href");
}
```

variation

```
$("td.need_link_here a", $("table tr td.important_column a[href=/bla/blah/link]").closest(tr)).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

Piece of js that would do the trick:

```
if($('.important_column a').text() == 'SOME TEXT YOU WANT')
{
   $('.important_column a').attr('href', $('.need_link_here a').attr('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(function() {
  column_text = $(".important_column a").text();
  if(column_text == "IMPORTANT INFO") {
    link_href = $(".need_link_here a").attr("href");
    alert(link_href);
  }
});
```

Check out [this working demo](http://jsbin.com/orizu3/edit).

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what the OP wants. Is this close?

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function ()
{
    var $tr = $(this);
    if($tr.find('td.important_column').text() === 'IMPORTANT INFO')
    {
        alert($tr.find('td.need_link_here > a').attr('href'))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.need_link_here a',
    jQuery('.important_column a:contains(IMPORTANT INFO)').parent() 
).attr('href');
```

Comment: OP wrote 'if the link text in "important_column" equals the thing im looking for' but you just look at the class.

Comment: @jAndy: Well, that's a very vague criticism (which doesn't suggest *why* it is 'terrible' or what could be done to improve it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next method to get siblings of a found item:

```
$('.important_column').next().next().attr("href")
```

will select the href of the 2nd td element after the one with class="important_column"

Comment: 1. Assumes that class is not significant. 2. Doesn't check the text. 3. Tries to get the value of the href attribute of the TD element.

Comment: @David Dorward: Isn't it quite obvious that "need_link_here" will not be present in the actual page? If it was, it would be quite trivial...

Comment: @snowlord: No, it isn't obvious, the question is open to quite a lot of interpretation. It isn't even clear if the "important_column" class would be there.