# Add HTML to node title in Drupal module, not in theme layer

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to add some functionality to my Drupal 6 module: I want to insert an image next to certain node titles (it involves a span and an img tag). I thought I could do this by just implementing mymodule_preprocess_node() and modifying the title. However, Drupal strips out all tags to avoid XSS attacks.

I've seen many solutions that involve the theme layer (most commonly http://drupal.org/node/28537), but I want to do this in my module, not in the theme. I don't want to modify any .tpl.php files or template.php. Can anyone give me tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you've tried preprocess_node(), and are correct that, if you are storing the img tag as part of the node title, Drupal will indeed strip that out, as it runs $node->title through check_plain in [template_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_node/6).

My suggestion would be to store the actual image as an image field (using some combination of the [imagefield](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) module and [imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) for sizing), set the display of that field to be hidden on the CCK display tab for the given content type, and then attach the image to be part of the $title variable in your module's preprocess function. This solution would also allow you to display that image next to the title in any views you may need to create.

Comment: Unfortunately the image changes - which image is displayed depends on how often this node has been loaded in comparison with other nodes.  So I can't just store a static image with the node - I need to look up which image to add each time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

By 'certain node titles' - do you mean all nodes titles from certain node types?

If so, you can likely style the node using only CSS. By default all nodes will have a class that corresponds to the node type. Using CSS background images, you can add an image to the node title.

Your module can call [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6) and add in any required CSS into the page. This way, it is theme independent.

Comment: This would work if I just needed to add an image, but it's more than just that.  However, I might be able to use this method if I can't find a way to get the HTML tags that I do need - getting the image to show up is better than nothing at all.  As I mentioned above, the image changes depending on the situation, so it looks like I'd have to have a different style sheet for each image and choose which style sheet to add at load time - does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier way is with javascript / Jquery. 
You create a Jquery script which is called only in certain types of nodes and pass the number of views from drupal to the jscript.

You can call drupal_add_js() inside your module_preprocess_node and pass a variable which contains the number of views or the image link to the script. Something like this:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js("var mymodule_imagelink = " . drupal_to_js($imagelink) . ";", 'inline');
drupal_add_js("my_js_file.js");
?>
```

then in my_js_file.js just change the text. There are several ways to acomplish this. For instance, you can do a search in the document and change the title to something else or you can use a determined ID, etc...

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/