# How to find text nodes with jquery

Tags: jquery

how can i select all text nodes with a textpattern.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>test</div>
<button>test</button>
<span title="test"></test>
</body>
</html>

$(select all nodes with text "test")
```

Comment: By "with a textpattern" do you mean "contain specific text"?

Comment: Do you actually want text nodes? Or do you want the element that contains the text node? `<div>test</div>` is 2 nodes. A type 1 element, and a type 3 text node.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`:contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('*:contains(test)')
```

Note that this won't search attributes.

Comment: That wouldn't select the text nodes, though, which is what he's apparently asking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about 'test' in the class name:

```
var elements = $('[class]*="test"');
```

Or if you're talking about 'test' in the text of the element:

```
var elements = %('*:contains("test")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously answered here:

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

(Short answer from the above stackoverflow question) ... use the :contains filter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the [contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

**The way #1**

> One of the standard filters for selecting elements based on their
>   content is the :contains(text) filter. It matches all elements which
>   contain the given text. Its major flaw is that it’s case-sensitive by
>   default. Personally, most of the time I don’t need a text comparison
>   to be case-sensitive. It is in general more intuitive for the
>   end-users to find the text they type no matter the casing. Quite a few
>   people on the Internet agree with me on this one. It was only a matter
>   of time when the case-insensitive version of the :contains filter
>   appeared on the Internet. An example of the alternative version is:
>
> ```
> jQuery.extend(
>     jQuery.expr[':'], {
>         Contains: "jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0"
>     } 
> );
> ```
>
> By converting both the selected text and the text that you’re looking
>   for to upper case before matching you can simulate a case-insensitive
>   search. The only difference between using the case-sensitive and
>   case-insensitive version as defined above is the capital letter C in
>   the filter’s name. Of course you could change it to anything else what
>   would make sense to you and other people working with your code.

**The way #2**

> As you might’ve noticed in the JavaScript snippet above, the contains
>   filter uses indexOf method of string to check whether the given string
>   contains a particular piece of text or not. While this method is
>   sufficient in most situations you may face scenarios when a simple
>   match is not enough. Using Regular Expressions might be just the
>   answer you’ve been looking for.
>
> It’s quite surprising that jQuery doesn’t ship with support for
>   Regular Expressions. I would definitely agree that they aren’t an
>   answer to everything and you should use them wisely. But if you want
>   to use them, and you have a good reason to do so, they are not there.
>   Luckily it’s not that difficult to extend jQuery with an extra Regular
>   Expressions-based Content Filter.
>
> ```
> jQuery.extend(
>     jQuery.expr[':'], {
>         regex: function(a, i, m, r) {
>             var r = new RegExp(m[3], 'i');
>             return r.test(jQuery(a).text());
>         }
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> Believe it or not, but the few lines of code above is all you need to
>   extend jQuery with support for regular expression text matches. What
>   the above does is to define a new filter called regex. Each time the
>   filter is called, it creates a new Regular Expression using the value
>   passed as the parameter of the filter. Additionally the expression
>   will use a case-insensitive match (you could remove it by deleting the
>   i from the second parameter of RegExp constructor). If the text of the
>   current DOM object matches the expression the object will be added to
>   the array of matches.
>
> You can use the regex filter as follows:
>
> ```
> $("p:regex('[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}')")
> ```
>
> The example above would return all paragraphs which contain an e-mail
>   address.

These two ways extend jQuery with a `:contains` and `:regex` filters (as author said, `jQuery ships with quite a few filters: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/`).

[via](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-regex-filter/)

There is also a `:regex` filter [plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/regex) if you wish.