# Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm starting the development of chrome extensions, i have read few tutorials but i still have few questions, like;

1) How to get the text of the page Like i want to in skype or google talk extesnion the number on any webpage are converted to PHONE LINK how can i do this?

2) How to perform authentication using the plugin like the google plus (gmail) checker, I want to do this for another website not gmail, i want to do this for me custom website.

Thanks

Comment: There is no Chrome API for this, everything would need to be done in javascript, just like if you were doing it on a regular web page. If you know how to do all this in javascript then transferring it to Chrome would be trivial, if you don't know how to do this in javascript then the question is too vague in its current form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) There are a number of ways to ways to find text on pages. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery) with jQuery.

2) Google has a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html) for using OAuth from an extension. This should work with most OAuth providers. You can also use cookies or [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) if you want something simpler.

Comment: can i use JQuery in an extension..cool i didn't know that..thanks.

Comment: also can you give me any working example of OAuth other than from the code.google.com site. thanks

Comment: I don't know of any other OAuth examples for Chrome extensions off the top of my head. Perhaps if you perform a Google search you can find one.