# How do I use jQuery to get a set of every element with certain text, but NOT the parents?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I want to use jQuery to select every element that has a certain text string in it, but not the parents of that element. How do I do this? I have no control whatsoever over the HTML code, but here is an example:

```
<body>
<div>
<p>This is a paragraph and <a>this is not</a>.</p>
Here we have a div.
</div>
</body>
```

If I use the word "this" as my match word, I want jQuery to provide me with a set containing the `<a>` and the `<p>`, but not the `<div>` or the `<body>`.

Again, I have no control AT ALL over the HTML!

Thanks!

** Clarification: I do want the parent of the element if the parent ALSO has a "this" in its immediate text. Thus, I want the `<a>` AND the `<p>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

This might help ;)

Comment: :contains will return the body and div as well as the p and the a. I just want the p and the a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update::**

Here is what I came up with: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JeeW/1/)

```
var myArray = $('*:contains("this")','body').filter(function(){
    if($(this).contents().filter(function(){
        return(this.nodeType == 3);
    }).text().indexOf('this')===-1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});


$.each(myArray,function(){
   console.log(this.nodeName); 
});
```

Starts similar to the link posted by Robin, but it forces to only search in the context of `body`  elements - this keeps your scripts safe if they are not inline.

The next part is a filter that checks to see if the current element direct text nodes contain the text.

This is a bit convoluted, but to walk through it:

`.contents()` - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) - gets the immediate nodes

`.filter()` - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - we want to only test on test nodes, so we filter them out

`this.nodeType` - [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1950641247) - check to see if its a text node

`.test()` - [docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/) - gets a string of the text nodes.

`.indexOf()` - check that string for our string

Note I did the `:contains()` at the top and in the second filter, the first isn't needed per say but I think the initial test should reduce the number of deeper tests and speed it up slightly.

Comment: I don't want to exclude nodes with children. That would kick the p out of the set. I want the p because it has a "this" in it. But I also want the a, because it also has a "this" in it.

Comment: Updated with something that keys off the actual child text nodes and should be better suited to your requirements

Comment: It still only finds the anchor tag, not the paragraph tag as well.

Comment: Figured it out. In my sample, 'this' was capitalized once and not the other time. I changed one line of your solution WSkid: .text().toLowerCase().indexOf('this')===-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [solution with pure JS](http://jsfiddle.net/XcUZe/1/).

Code:

`function findElmsWithWord(word, elm, found){
    if (elm.nodeType === 3 && elm.data.indexOf(word) !== -1)
        found.push(elm.parentNode);
    else
        for (var i = 0; i < elm.childNodes.length; i++)
            findElmsWithWord(word, elm.childNodes[i], found);
}`

var elms = [];
findElmsWithWord('this', document.body, elms);
console.log(elms);

It recursively walks the dom until it finds the text nodes that contain the word in question. And then adds the text node's parent as a result.

Comment: This solution is only finding the anchor tag. I am looking for a way to get both the anchor and the paragraph (well, any element that 'owns' the word, which in this case is the p and the a).

Comment: It *does* do what you want. Did you try running the fiddle?

Comment: No sir, but I tested it in FireFox w/ notepad. Maybe the problem was the capitalization, like WSkid's solution above. I've already marked his as the answer though (once I figured out the capitalization thing) -- since he did provide a jQuery solution, which is what I was originally seeking.