# Find text spanning multiple nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

I'm searching a way to find text spanning multiple nodes in similar way Firefox does it, eg.

With given HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet.</p>
```

When I search for text "ipsum dolor" by ctrl+f Firefox will selects that text, ie. will create Range object(s).

I know I can easily search for text within text nodes (vide [Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)) but this doesn't work in above example.

Comment: so you mean to ignore the tags?

Comment: In a manner of speaking - yes, but I also must have ability to create Range (ie. select that text, emphasize it somehow). Sorry if I haven't stand it clear.

Answer (score 1):

This will select all `p` elements that contain the text specified as an argument to `indexOf`. The `text` method gets the contents of all text nodes of an element, so the `b` tag in your example will not matter:

```
$("p").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf("ipsum dolor") > -1;  
});
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/ngJG6/).

Comment: Yes, it works in that case, but I want to ephasize only that text (ipsum dolor) in your example.

Comment: I think the only way is to develop some sophisticated algorithm that does the job

Comment: Is there any chance that this has gotten easier in the last eight years?

Answer (score 1):

[`window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.find) is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Discussion over at whatwg.org suggests it's not in Opera :-( http://developers.whatwg.org/dnd.html#text-search-apis

Comment: Yes :(. This works in FF, Chrome, Safari. In IE I can use TextRange object. But I can not find similar functionality in Opera :/