# Jquery: Look up a word in a div and load php script

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a a lot of texts and a script called "test.php" elsewhere.

I want to look up a word, lets say "oranges" in the div class "paragraph", and if there is "oranges" word in there, i want it to load test.php

I looked at the examples for find() function but i failed to make it work as i wanted it to.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find text string using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "load test.php" - you have 3 different interpretations here, which one is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load test.php and put it's contents in the div with class paragraph if that div contains the text "oranges":

```
$('div.paragraph:contains("oranges")').load('test.php');
```

Comment: this works great, but the "oranges" text gets replaced. Is there a way to make it stay?

Comment: Found it out myself by loading it into another div :) thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(".paragraph").text().indexOf("oranges") > -1) {
    $.get("script.php", function() {
       //Loaded!
    });  
}
```

This gets the `text` of `.paragraph` and checks whether that string contains the text "oranges" using the native JavaScript `indexOf` method. If the string does contain the specified text, you can load your script.

Note that this will be case sensitive, so if you also wanted to match "Oranges", you could use the `toLowerCase` method before `indexOf`, or use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".paragraph:contains('Oranges')").length > 0) {
    location.href = 'test.php';
}
```

The `find()` function is used to find descendants of the jQuery object whose `find()` you are calling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gonna try and let you know :)