# JScript: how to check if a string contains a specific word?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find a way to check if a string contains a specific sequence of characters in JScript.
In my case, I am trying to see if the string is "DPObject" followed by a number. Such as "DPObject3" or "DPObject14".

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
if (/DPObject\d+/.test(string)) {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript String has an indexOf method you can use to check if a String contains a particular substring .

If you need to test for patterns , like "DPObject" followed by an integer , probably you need to use Regexes . ( http://www.regular-expressions.info )

It's javascript , or js for short - not JScript .

Comment: This question is about JScript. Not javascript. So your response is unhelpful and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should use a regular expression. I think this would be something like :

```
var re = new RegExp("^DPObject([0-9]+)$");
re.test(someString);
```

This ensures there is at least only one digit after DPObject.
The "^" at the beginning is to ensure the string starts with DPObject. Check references on regexps for this kind of problems :)
edit: added "$" to mark the end of the string, the updated should be more "solid"

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways:

1. Use Javascripts [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method
2. Use Javascript [Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)
3. Use JQuery's [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery) function

Regular expressions are the most powerful and elegant way of doing it. They syntax makes sense after a while (honestly).  ;-)

Good luck.