# Use jQuery .filter() to select specific text within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

HTML:

```
<p class="greeting">
  hello, my name is kevin. what's yours?
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$("p.greeting").filter(function (){
  return $this.text() === "my name is";
}).css("background", "green");
```

I'm trying to isolate the words "my name is" in the `<p class="greeting">` tag.  Can anyone help me with the jQuery as it doesn't seem to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

CSS:

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = 'My namE iS';

$( 'p.greeting' ).html( function ( i, html ) {
    var regexp, replacement;

    regexp = RegExp( '(' + text + ')', 'gi' );
    replacement = '<span class="highlight">$1</span>';

    return html.replace( regexp, replacement );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SGCDS/5/

Comment: This looks good, although to completely meet the question's requirements, you should set some class on that <span> and then .css that class to "green" background.

Comment: awesome thanks!  is there a straightforward way to have `var text` to be case-insensitive?

Comment: @Bruce Good advice. I already did that. I prefer the yellow background color. The OP can change it to green...

Comment: for case-insensitive I'd go regex: /my name is (.*)/i

Comment: @pruett I've updated my answer with a new improved solution (based on regular expressions). The `'gi'` flag ensures that the search is global and case-insensitive.

Comment: thanks @ŠimeVidas I don't quite understand everything in your code, but it works great!  Time for me to deconstruct what you did :)

Comment: @pruett Read the MDN pages for [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

You're function returns always false. Only if there is exactly "my name is" in your div, it will return true.

Try something like this:

```
return $(this).text().indexOf("my name is") != -1;
```

Comment: hmm...doesn't seem to work.  is the -1 a nodeType?  i'm not familiar with this

Comment: I believe the claim is that if text() doesn't contain the sub-string "my name is" then .indexOf() will return -1.