# Selected text inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this text inside `<div>` to be highlighten (selected for copy) when page loads.

```
<div id='sample_div'>This is sample text</div>
```

**What i tried:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#sample_div').select();

});
```

Comment: `$('#sample_div').highlight();`

Comment: Please see this article for additional help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959050/use-jquery-filter-to-select-specific-text-within-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I assume correctly, you want the text inside a particular div to be highlighted..

```
function selectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { //ms
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) { //all others
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/KcX6A/1507/)

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/903324)**

Answer (score 2):

The solution change based on the current browser, with older version of jQuery I use `$.browser`, but now is deleted; to check it's IE and use the correct code check if `document.body.createTextRange` exist like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    selectText('sample_div');
});

function selectText(element) {
    var text = document.getElementById(element);
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    } 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/bKPcX/