# How to select div text on button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select the div content on click button.

HTML

```
 <div id="divid">Hello This div content have to be select. </div>
 <button onclick="selectText(divid);"> Select Div</button>
```

JS

```
   function selectText(divid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var div = document.body.createTextRange();

            div.moveToElementText(document.getElementById("divid"));
            div.select();
        }
        else {
            var div = document.createRange();
            div.setStartBefore(document.getElementById("divid"));
            div.setEndAfter(document.getElementById("divid"));

            window.getSelection().addRange(div);
        }

    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/xds4y0en/

Comment: I just tried it on my Windows Visual Studio and it worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selected text inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611992/selected-text-inside-div)

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/nk1pc8h9/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the below @Rajagopal Subramanian

```js
 function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="divid">Hello This div content have to be select.</div>
<button onclick="selectText('divid')">Select</button>
```

Comment: this might fail if you have text selected on Chrome.
I had to add this: `window.getSelection().empty();` before the `addRange` call to avoid an error in console `Discontiguous selection is not supported.`

Answer (score 1):

```
function selectText(containerid) {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Deprecation] The behavior that Selection.addRange() merges existing Range and the specified Range was removed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632 for more details.

Answer (score -3):

I hope it will help you.

**html code**

```
<div id="divid">Hello This div content have to be select. </div>
        <button id="hit"> Select Div</button>
```

**demo.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hit').on('click', function(){
        var sav = $('#divid').html();
        alert(sav);
    });
});
```

Comment: This question hasn't been tagged with jQuery and the OP doesn't use it in the example or the fiddle.  You haven't even mentioned in your answer that the OP will need to add the jQuery library

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that