# Using jquery to search and return results on a page

Tags: jquery, html, search

Currently I have alot of information that are in several different divs.

I want to be able to search this information (that is all on the same page) and print the results in a div, without having to use mysql.

I.e, if I searched for 'chair' all the results with 'chair' would appear in a div.

How would I go about doing this? I am rather new to jquery, but I am enjoying learning its amazing powers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to use jQuery, then you could do something like that:

```
var wordToSearch = "house";
$("div:contains('" + wordToSearch + "')").each(function() {
    $("#result").append(this.innerText);
});
```

Here is jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/GEyey/

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is figure out which tags you want to make searchable. I'd assign a CSS class to the divs you want to make searchable. Then something like this would work:

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
    $('div.searchable').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
            //Do something.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could start reading this:

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

If not here you have a very good approach:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/6-more-jquery-tips-text-searching-page-load-time-and-others.html

Answer (score -1):

U could iterate through all Divs, check if one of them has the Text "chair" and add the text in your ResultDataDiv (It could look something like that):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
   if (divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf("chair"){
     $("#myDataDiv").innerHTML = divs[i].innerHTML;
   }                               
}
```

If you want an event to work on your page, you should call it inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: 1. You are searching only "div" tags. What about "p", "span" and so on? 2. You should use at least .indexOf() not equals operator, because your solution implies that div contains only searched word. 3. div[i].innerHTML = "chair" should be ==, I guess.

Comment: According to the Question, I quote: "Currently I have alot of information that are in several different divs."

Comment: Updated the Answer, I did it on the fly, so that he has an Idea of how he could achieve this >.<

Comment: I sort of understand, but the rabbit hole gets slightly deeper.

Comment: woops hit enter...

lets say I have a table with a row
`<tr><td>chair</td><td>$19.50</td></tr>`

is it possible to do the search then return that table row?