# How to Create HTML jQuery Find Tool Similar to MS-Word Find

Tags: jquery

Someone wants me to create a find tool with jQuery similar to Microsoft Word's find tool -- with Next and Previous buttons. Luckily the HTML content being search should just be a single, small static HTML page. So i doubt there would be server-side involvement.

Are there any jQuery widgets out there that do this kind of thing? Or does someone have examples (or high level description) of how to build this out without server-side involvement?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/live-search/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find and highlight a string in html look at this question.

[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)