# html tag or class to specific words with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, tags

I'm running a `wordpress` website in which there are a few words that should always be in `italic` (due to botanic reasons).

I'm trying to find a way to automatically modify those words, so that I don't need to do it manually.

Is there a `JS` or `JQuery` that can do the job and find those words in texts and titles of the pages and wrap around them a tag `<em>` or a tag with `class`?

I read in a post I will need to parse the html code in order to ensure that I only emphasize keywords and not invisible text or code (such as alt text attributes for images or actual markup).

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

```
function change() {
var words = new Array("Just", "Dan", "Man", "Dan");
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'g');
    var html = html.replace(reg, "<i>"+words[i]+"</i>");
}
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
change();
```

Define An Array and It will Loop through each word and will replace each occurence of specific word.

Comment: I tried your method and I can't seem to make it work though. Am I missing something? Underneath I post the example. Thanks again for the precious help!

Comment: `<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quick Test</title>

<script>

function change() {
var words = new Array("Nymphaea", "Nelumbo", "Iris", "Hemerocallis", "Hibiscus");
var html = document.body.innerHTML;
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'g');
    var html = html.replace(reg, "<i>"+words[i]+"</i>");
}
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
change();

</script>



</head>

<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<h1>Nymphaea Test</h1>

<p>Some more text and Nymphaea and more...</p>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: The code works as it should, but it goes at the end of the body. You are calling it before there is any text to work on.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm back with another problem. Firstly I excuse myself for not marking the answer as accepted, which is something I forgot to do! I have not been visiting for quite a long time the website I asked help for and I just realized that there's still something not working correctly with this method. When I pass over the pictures, the title appears with a < i > tag on the name Nymphaea or Nelumbo etc. Is there a way to modify this js in order to target titles and make them be written correctly without showing the < i > tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find for tags which contains certain words

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

     <div>John Resig</div>

     <div>George Martin</div>
     <div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
     <div>J. Ohn</div>

<script>

 $("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you post your code i can help you more, See this post [Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)