# Find and replace dollar sign with rupee symbol using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

This is my code in which I am trying to replace Dollar Symbol `&#36;` with INR(Indian Rupee) using jQuery, however it is not working  as this is only a specimen code so it is not `ul >li` and `find text` and `replace text` kinda thing, my tries goes like this- I tried to first gather whole HTML and then replace `$` sign with the code, but its not making anyhow.

My assumption - in `$(document).ready()` using `$(this)` inside this snippet refers to the document, let me know if **this is a false assumption**, as I tried my attempts keeping this thing in mind.

Please `DO NOT` give any links/referrals to do it in CSS way or Webrupee API usage, keep it simple to jQuery this time :)

**My Code** -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rupee Change - jQuery Flavour</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>This is a price listing with &#36; sign, Now I wanted to replace each dollar sign with rupee symbol</p>
<ul>
<li>&#36; 500</li>
<li>&#36; 600</li>
<li>&#36; 700</li>
<li>&#36; 800</li>
<li>&#36; 900</li>
</ul>

 <div id="showhtml"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).html().replace("$", "<del>&#2352;</del>");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

FYI - I also tried this way of handling but not working :( [find-text-string-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

Comment: you need to reassign it back to the html. $(this).html($(this).html().replace("$", "<del>&#2352;</del>"));

Comment: @ParthikGosar not working :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ is a special character in Regex. You will need to escape it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var replaced = $('body').html().replace(/\$/g, "<del>&#2352;</del>");
    $('body').html(replaced);
});
```

Comment: This helped me, but for some reason I had to use two slashes to get it to work with a dollar sign, like so: replace(/\\$/g, "<del>&#2352;</del>");