# Wrap Each * on a Page Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to wrap each asterisks on a page with `<span class="red"></span>`. The few things I've tried don't work. I think what this boils down to is that I need to search the page for a specific character, and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I am sure there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I second Vega's comment, in that, this would be resource intensive being as you would have to check the entire page for a specific character.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, but basically it's just easier to do this than to rework an entire script I've written for a page.

Comment: @Blazemonger: That's incorrect, `$("*")` will return a collection of *all* elements.

Comment: I realized the problem with the `*`, but that still doesn't help me figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Rev So what do you want to do?

Comment: Are we looking for text or elements here?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

Comment: @Dave: Not really, that question is about searching for a string, not handling the replacement of all occurrences of that string.

Comment: @MMM The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/926964/21909 would at least be a good starting point.

Comment: True, you're right, however it's not a _duplicate_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For not replacing the entire HTML (*really bad attitude*), we can do fast manipulation with elements:

```
var specialTags = ["script", "style"].join("|"),
    re = new RegExp("^(?:" + specialTags + ")$", "i");

for (var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i = els.length; i--;) {
    var el = els[i];

    if (re.test(el.tagName))
        continue;

    for (var j = 0, childs = el.childNodes, lj = childs.length; j < lj; j++) {
        var child = childs[j];
        if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.indexOf("*") > -1) {
            var segments = child.nodeValue.split("*");
            for (var k = 0, lk = segments.length; k < lk; k++) {
                el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(segments[k]), child);
                if (k < lk - 1) {
                    var span = document.createElement("span");
                    span.className = "red";
                    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*"));
                    el.insertBefore(span, child);
                }
            }
            el.removeChild(child);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pure JavaScript which does not require jQuery, that can't really help here.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4ZXA/5/

Comment: +999, I was _so_ close to this, got stuck on the splitting part ;)

Comment: The ***REAL SPEED*** of this approach is demonstrated here: http://jsperf.com/replace-text-with-tag.

Comment: +1 Remember to add the `*` to the contents of the tag (that's what the OP wanted)

Comment: This will replace * inside script and style tags.

Comment: This will also replace content in the `<head>`

Comment: @MMM What do you mean? `<head>` shouldn't contain text nodes with asterisks.

Comment: @VisioN: How about `<title>My ** website</title>`? Never heard that the spec does not allow that.

Comment: @MMM Then it is `<title>` and not `<head>`. Just add `title` to `specialTags` array, and the script will skip it.

Comment: @MMM Of course if you need to remove entire `<head>` from operating queue, it is better to use `querySelectorAll("body, body *")` instead of `getElementsByTagName("*")`. However `querySelector` is available only in modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, yes, all you're saying is true and known to me, I've merely stated that if anything in the head has an asterisk, it will get replaced too ;) No need to explain yourself!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?...

**http://jsfiddle.net/n3Sqn/**

```
 $("body:contains(*)").contents().each(function() {
  if(this.nodeType == 1)
  {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\*/g, "<span class=\"red\">*</span>"))
  }
});
```

Comment: You would want to do this on nodeType == 3 so as not to replace * in html

Comment: I was initially trying that but then it doesnt replace the text in the html so i needed to get that particular text's parent node.. hence tried use Nodetype element. Probably i was doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit dirty and risky (explained below), but you could try the following:

```
var allHTML = $("body").html();
allHTML = allHTML.replace(/\*/g, "<span class=\"red\">*</span>");
$("body").html(allHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6rDK4/

Note: As Dogbert pointed out this might replace `*` characters that are within HTML tags, e.g. node attributes.

**EDIT**: Bear in mind that this might reattach all the scripts you have in your body though! Try replacing `body` with your main container.

**EDIT2**: VisioN posted a more elaborate but a lot safer solution.

Comment: This would replace "*" in node attributes too.

Comment: @Dogbert: That's true, however I don't think you use such characters in attributes often? I'll add this to the answer though.

Comment: ugh. Unfortunately the things that I'm trying to edit do have * in the attributes. Thanks, though, this would solve the problem otherwise. I'll just have to do this statically, which is going to take much longer.

Comment: @Rev Never never never replace entire markup in a way like this. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239900/1249581) as the way how it *should* be done.

Comment: @VisioN: I agree, that's why I wrote it's dirty and risky, your answer is brilliant though.

Answer (score 2):

Without using jQuery so it might be a little faster, and definitely not dependent on libs:

```
(function(str,e){
    var regex = new RegExp(str, 'gi');
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<span class="red">*</span>');
})('*',document.body);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same drawbacks though.

Answer (score 1):

This will work and not replace * in tags it shouldn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/DR6Ca/2/

```
var text = $("body").find(":contains(*)").contents().filter(function() {
    //Don't include css or script tags, all other text nodes are fine.
  return this.nodeType == 3
      && ($(this).parent().get(0).tagName.toUpperCase() !== "SCRIPT") 
      && ($(this).parent().get(0).tagName.toUpperCase() !== "STYLE");
}).replaceWith(function() {
   return this.textContent.replace(/\*/g, "<span class=\"red\">*</span>");
```

You can test the others code in this jsfiddle to see if they keep the "hi" blue or not.  If it doesn't stay blue they have a bug.