# Wrap character in String, excluding a Link tag with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

EDIT

heres what i have to do...

Imagine if i have a text with some html tags inside it (it is still a string):

```
var string = '<p>Hello, my name is Mauricio</p><p>Hi, my name is Patricia</p><p class="warn">Yeah, My name is Carl</p><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>';
```

And i want to wrap all the letters "a" with

```
 <span class="ui-match"></span>
```

but i must not replace anything from the  tag, neither what is inside it, neither the class in the

element.

So if I want to wrap all the letters "a" from that string, it would return like that:

```
<p>Hello, my n<span class="ui-match">a</span>me is M<span class="ui-match">a</span>uricio</p><p>Hi, my n<span class="ui-match">a</span>me is P<span class="ui-match">a</span>trici<span class="ui-match">a</span></p><p class="warn">Ye<span class="ui-match">a</span>h, My n<span class="ui-match">a</span>me is C<span class="ui-match">a</span>rl</p><a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
```

all the letters "a" where wrapped with

```
 <span class="ui-match"></span>
```

, but the link and the paragraph were not.

also this string is comming from a API, so its dynamic... this letter i'm searching is dynamic, so it can be "a" or "abc"... it must not be case sensitive

thanks

Comment: Are you only able to use regex, or can you use regex in combination with other functions?

Comment: You can combine everything... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to split the problem into 2 smaller problems:

1. grab text content of all tags.
2. wrap chars with `<span class="ui-match"></span>`

Using [RegExp to parse HTML is a **bad** idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) but in this case since you seem to *control* the input structure you might use it to simplify the logic.

Using a single RegExp for it will be really hard, so it's also better to do 2 `String#replace` instead of one. A generic implementation would be like:

```
function replaceHtmlContent(str, match, replaceFn) {
  // we use the "g" and "i" flags to make it replace all occurrences and ignore case
  var re = new RegExp(match, 'gi');
  // this RegExp will match any char sequence that doesn't contain "<" or ">"
  // and that is followed by a tag
  return str.replace(/([^<>]+)(?=<[^>]+>)/g, function(s, content){
    return content.replace(re, replaceFn);
  });
}
```

which could be abstracted as:

```
function wrapMatch(src, match) {
  return replaceHtmlContent(src, match, function(str){
    return '<span class="ui-match">'+ str +'</span>';
  });
}
```

and used later like:

```
var output = wrapMatch(input, 'a');
```

which would give the expected result for the example input.

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ovUFEsas/4/edit

Answer (score 2):

Does this solution matches your requirements?

```
string = string.replace(/a(?![^<]*?>)/g, '<span class="ui-match">a</span>');
```

A little help about `(?![^<]*?>)` (roughly : "some text not followed by `>`") :

```
(?!...)   not followed by
[^<]*     any char except "<", zero or more times
?>        until next ">"
```

Wrapped inside a function :

```
function replace(html, text, replacement) {
    // RegExp.escape : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1636522
    var re = new RegExp('(' + RegExp.escape(text) + ')(?![^<]*?>)', 'g');
    return html.replace(re, replacement);
}
```

```js
var html = '<a class="azerty"> azerty &lt; azerty </a>';
html = replace(html, 'azerty', '<b>$1</b>');
// "<a class="azerty"> <b>azerty</b> &lt; <b>azerty</b> </a>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wared... but the answer from Miller Meideiros seem to be simpler, and is working great. but i really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @MauricioSoares You're welcome :D Be careful though, your choice fails the same way.

Comment: @MauricioSoares Forget what I've told you previously, actually there can't be any `<` and `>` between tags since we have to replace them with HTML entities, respectively `&lt;` and `&gt;`. So, obviously, "your choice fails the same way"... I have to review my answer entirely ^^' Stupid me.

Comment: @MauricioSoares I'm reverted back to the first revision :D

Comment: @MauricioSoares And added a function for convenience :)

Answer (score 1):

For not using regex, it will be faster to work with DOM nodes:

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
    children;

div.innerHTML = 'Hello, my name is mauricio, and i like <a href="#">Star Wars</a>';
children = div.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(children[i]);
    if (children[i].nodeType === 3) {
        children[i].nodeValue = children[i].nodeValue.replace(/a/g, 'R');
    }
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

**N.B.:** I used `innerHTML` property as an example way here, however it is not recommended to exploit it because of a rather low performance.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/N7rdW/

---

### UPDATE:

As per your update, you should better use the approach from my answer for another question from [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239900/1249581). The code is a bit more complicated but is rather fast (not keeping in mind `innerHTML` usage):

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'Hello, my name is mauricio, and i like <a href="#">Star Wars</a>';

for (var i = 0, children = div.childNodes, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.indexOf('a') > -1) {
        var segments = child.nodeValue.split('a');
        for (var k = 0, lk = segments.length; k < lk; k++) {
            div.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(segments[k]), child);
            if (k < lk - 1) {
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.className = 'ui-match';
                span.appendChild(document.createTextNode('R'));
                div.insertBefore(span, child);
            }
        }
        div.removeChild(child);
    }
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4ZXA/6/

Comment: Thanks Vision! i'm sorry but i formulated my question wrong... i just updated it... i dont want to replace, i want to wrap with a tag

Comment: @MauricioSoares Then you should better use my other answer for the similar question from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16239900/1249581.

Comment: hey @VisioN, do you mind creating an example that works with my string? I don't think i got your answer really well...

also, is there a way to do this without creating an element? only manipulating the string?

Comment: @MauricioSoares Please see my updated answer. FYI, you should [*never try to parse HTML with regex*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1249581).

Comment: Thanks, i'm testing your answer... :)

Comment: Hey @VisioN, i tested your solution but i got some problems... i just discovered that the structured of the string is a little bit more complex... i updated the question... would u take a look please? Thanks for your patience =)