# Find certain text on page and make it underlined

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I find certain text on my web page and make it underlined?

For example, I have some text on my page and I want to find all the words `hello` and make them underlined.

My trial code is:

```
$( "body:contains('hello')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

But this ends up underlining the whole line instead of just that word.

Comment: and your trial code is?

Comment: is there any specific `class , id , div , span` around that text? show your code then only we can suggest the solution.

Comment: Related helpful post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

Comment: @Era, that's the problem, the hello word could be in any html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

**HTML**

```
<p>For example, I have some text on my page and I want to find all the words hello and make them bold.</p>
```

**Script**

```
$('p').html( $('p').html().replace(/hello/g, '<strong>hello</strong>') )
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xpBL6/)

Comment: This will only work with P tags, I need it to work on all html tags.

Comment: `$('p')` change to `$('*')`.

Comment: @oshirowanen you need to take some initiative... There is one problem here, you'll loose all events bound to children of targeted elements, if any

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('body').html($('body').html().replace(/hello/g, '<strong>hello</strong>') )
```

Comment: this won't work! he want to make it bold not to add border to whole sentence.

Comment: This kind of works because I replaced the css with "`font-weight","bold"`, however, instead of making that single word bold, it makes the whole line bold.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
     $('*:contains("hello")').css( "text-decoration", "underline");
});
```

please review this code