# Converting a Text NodeType into an Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is sort of [a continuation of an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855236/how-can-i-find-text-in-html-with-jquery/25855440#25855440).

I have some html.

```
<h3>things that are red:</h3>
<ul>
   <li><a href="html://www.redapples.com">Red Apples</a></li>
   <li><a href="html://www.redmeat.com">Red Meat</a></li>
   <li><a href="html://www.redcar.com">All Red Cars</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to use javascript to wrap all of the text elements with a  element

The result I am looking for.

```
<h3>things that are <span class="red">red</span>:</h3>
<ul>
   <li><a href="html://www.redapples.com"><span class="red">Red</span> Apples</a></li>
   <li><a href="html://www.redmeat.com"><span class="red">Red</span> Meat</a></li>
   <li><a href="html://www.redcar.com">All <span class="red">Red</span> Cars</a></li>
</ul>
```

After a lot of thought I realized that I had to distinguish between text nodeTypes and Element NodeTypes while navigating the DOM.  I used some of the feedback from my earlier question, and wrote this little script.

```
function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walkTheDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

walkTheDOM(document.body, function (node) {
// Is it a Text node?       
if (node.nodeType === 3) { 
    var text = node.data.trim();
    // Does it have non white-space text content?       
    if (text.length > 0) {              
        node.data = text.replace(/(RED)/gi, '<span class="red">$1</span>'); 
    }
}
});
```

This does pretty much what I want it to do, except the output is text rather than html.  So my question is this, is there an easy way to fix this line

```
node.data = text.replace(/(RED)/gi, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
```

So that the output is html?

Comment: `node.innerHTML = text.replace...` Shouldn't have been very difficult to research this yourself

Comment: @charlietfl: That will break for `<li>&gt;/li&lt; bug</li>`, for example, unless you make sure to reencode things. `document.createElement` way is safer (but definitely more cumbersome).

Comment: Are you sure the innerHTML is an object at this level?  I've tried adding it, and I get nothing.

Comment: @charlieftl Yeah, innerHTML isn't a property of Text Objects.  So the question remains, is there an easy way convert a text object into an html object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do to make this generic, as I have hinted in the comment, is to create a new element, put the text node into it, then replace the text node with the new element.

```
function wrapTextNode(textNode) {
    var spanNode = document.createElement('span');
    spanNode.setAttribute('class', 'red');
    var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(textNode.textContent);
    spanNode.appendChild(newTextNode);
    textNode.parentNode.replaceChild(spanNode, textNode);
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
    var textNode = el.childNodes[0];
    wrapTextNode(textNode);
});
```

**EDIT:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qveqdf2/)

Comment: Great. How to do its reverse? That is, replace span.red with its text node.

Comment: Per SO rules, one question per question. So, make a new question; feel free to link it here if you want. But basically, run `cloneNode` on the text node, use `after` to insert it after its `parentNode`, then `remove` the old parent node.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/z2ymd5a7/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('li a').html(function(i,html) {
        return html.replace(/(RED)/gi, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I would love to go that way, but I for a lot of reasons I need to go only on text elements which means I can't narrow it down by 'li a' selectors.  And if I just go straight to the 'li' selector the replace wraps the 'red' in the href link which is why I resorted to using the DOM.

Comment: If you intend to manipulate `text nodes` just bear in mind that the result will always be `text`; therefore any tags would `< and >` would be escaped, as is the case in your result. To manipulate `HTML` you have to start off with HTML.

Comment: Thanks.  That's the best answer so far.  I was beginning to suspect that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Amadan is perfect to manipulate (convert from textnode to element for css purposes) for instance some VAT-text-information in the cart-totals section on the cart page in the storefront-child-theme in woocommerce in wordpress. There is no other usual or better way of changing this little piece of textnode that lies within a div containing different textnodes and elementnodes. So i wanted to say thanks for this solution.

Of course, this only works if you use only one language.

```
var cart_totals = document.querySelector(".cart_totals .shop_table");
if( !!cart_totals ) {
  for( var x = 0; x < cart_totals.childNodes.length; x++ ) {
    if( cart_totals.childNodes[x].nodeType === 3 && 
        cart_totals.childNodes[x].nodeValue.includes( 'inkl. 19 % MwSt.' ) ) {
      var textNode = cart_totals.childNodes[x];
      wrapTextNode( textNode ); /* see function from Amadan above */
    }
  }
}
```