# How to search the word in string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to search the word using jquery. I have used below code

```
child_name="Fasia_Cube.006";

if (child_name.toLowerCase().indexOf("fasia") >= 0){
    alert("fasia fond");
}
```

Fasic will come anyplace. How to solve this. Please any one help?

Comment: What issue are you facing with this code?

Comment: i don't see the problem

Comment: if word found not come inside the if condition

Comment: it comes in the if statement the way you have posted it

Comment: Please run the code then tell

Comment: 'How do I add 2 numbers in jquery?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text string using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code works fine**.

But see that you can also use the [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method, that searches a string for a specified value, and returns the position of the match. The search value can be string or a regular expression. This method returns `-1` if no match is found.

**Note**: Using regular expression and the flag `i` you do not need to call [String.prototype.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```js
var child_name = 'Fasia_Cube.006';

if (child_name.search(/fasia/i) >= 0) {
  console.log('fasia fond');
}
```