# How to get class name of element has specific text using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, classname

I need a JavaScript or jQuery way of extracting the Class name of DIV element by the text it contains.

Let's illustrate. If I had let's say following code:

```
<div class="_className">UniqueText</div>
```

I need to to know how to programmatically do something like this:

```
getClassNameWhereText("UniqueText");
```

In this case output should be:

```
_className
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this thread might meet your needs http://stackoverflow.com/a/926633/1970773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an id for your div, as per your information your text will be unique.

```
<div id="UniqueText" class="_className">UniqueText</div>
```

and the js code will be

```
function getClassNameWhereText(text){
    var className = $('#'+text).attr('class');
    console.log(className);
}
```

**UPDATE :** if you want to using contains
then you can do this,

```
function getClassNameWhereText(text){
    var val = document.getElementById(text).value;
    if(text.indexOf(val)>=0){
        var className = $('#'+text).attr('class');
        console.log(className);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like this way, as it's a pure JavaScript, no reliance on jQuery. I've tested it in this plunk: https://embed.plnkr.co/T5FLMg5oCq41p2H22A1w/ . The only issue I see is that it doesn't output all occurrences. How would you go about looping through all results?

Comment: If you like pure js then why did you tag your question with jQuery?

Comment: @Endless, I've asked for JavaScript or jQuery, but why would I load jQuery and inflate the size of my script, if there is a pure JavaScript one liner that can do this. Please don't be offended, but this is in my opinion a most elegant way of achieving the result.

Comment: @jjj you can iterate your all div by using `document.getElementsByTagName("div");` this. noted that this only works for simple `div`, not for nested `div`.

Comment: You used jquery in code but select element by javascript!

Answer (score 3):

JQuery [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector select element has specific text but it isn't exact. For example

```
$("div:contains(UniqueText)")
```

Select both of bottom divs

```
<div class="_className">UniqueText</div>
<div class="_className2">UniqueText2</div>
```

---

You can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter selected element by text.

```
var className = $("*").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "UniqueText";
}).attr("class");
```

```js
var className = $("*").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() == "UniqueText";
}).attr("class");

console.log(className);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_className">UniqueText</div>
<div class="_className2">UniqueText2</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

By getting all the `div` with each function you can search through all the divs and place a condition in which you the value of the `div` is equal to the particular text that you want to find. Then get the class name by using `.attr('class')`.

```js
 $( "div" ).each(function(){
       if($(this).text() == "UniqueText"){
        var output = $(this).attr('class');
        $(".output").html(output);
       }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="_classname">UniqueText</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

It might be a bit long for a code but it gets the work done nicely. :)

Comment: I like this... thanks a lot. Will it work for nested DIVs as well?

Comment: Yes as long as it is a div. It will search for all the `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:contains(word)](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
var className = $( "div:contains('John')" ).attr("class");
console.log(className)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="foo">John Resig</div>
<div class="bar">George Martin</div>
<div class="foo">Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div class="baz">J. Ohn</div>
```

Comment: But it would return any ancestor of div containing text too if this div is wrapped inside any other div

Comment: I need to know the class name. How is this outputting name of the class that contains the unique text?

Comment: Changed so it returns the class name

Comment: Still this failed e.g [here](https://jsfiddle.net/46kws8dq/). A workaround could be to use `$("div:contains('John'):not(:has(:contains('John')))")` but still `:contains()` isn't a strict matching filter

Comment: can still be useful if you are searching for some text like `John Bob` where the word is seperated `<div><i>John</i><br><i>bob</i><div>` but it's also possible to use `:last`

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster than using jQuery (but a bit more to type):

```js
var xpath = "//div[text()='UniqueText']";
var result = document.evaluate(xpath,
    document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE);
var node = result.singleNodeValue;
if (node) {
  console.log(node.className);
} else {
  console.error("Not found!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_className">UniqueText</div>
```

The reason is, browser's CSS selectors don't support `:contains` selector, and jQuery needs to emulate it by checking every node matching the rest of the selector. Ditto for using `.filter`. But XPath is done natively by the browser.

You also cannot specify exact match using the jQuery `:contains`, like here. If substring matching was indeed needed, you can change the XPath:

```
var xpath = "//div[contains(text(),'UniqueText')]";
```

XPath is very powerful, but a bit finicky and largely unknown, so I find it is very under-utilised, even when its use would be a perfect fit.