# CSS styling based on words in the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some text that I've fetched from an API and need to wrap a word in it, say "Biography", with `<span>` and `</span>` tags so that I can style it differently from the surrounding text. How I can use jQuery or JavaScript to do this?

Comment: Here is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/926964/920557

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .big{ font-size: 55px;  }
</style>
<script>
function chng(){
    var text = document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML;
    var text2 = text.replace('Germany','<span class="big">Germany</span>');
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = text2;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="pText">
Brazil - England - Germany
</p>
<button onclick="chng()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly the kind of solution I'm looking for, but without having it change on click. Is there anyway to change it automatically on page load?

Comment: Just call the function on body tag:
    <body onload="chng()">

Answer (score -1):

How are the words supposed to be chosen for wrapping (although we don't know what you mean)?
It seems you have to do this on your content generation (in PHP, .Net, asp, ect).
So you create the classes on css and use them on content generation, something like 
(php): echo 'This is mytext.';
(css): .big {font-weight: bold; font-size: 40px;}

Comment: I'm using a Wordpress plugin to insert Google Sheets data. It comes in in the form of unstyled tables.  The tables themselves don't have any specific css, so I cannot target anything specific in the table, unless I inject styling via javascript based on specific words.

Comment: I thing I got it. See new answer